# php artisan command not showing the correct output

Tags: laravel, git-bash, laravel-artisan

I am typing the command `php artisan` in my Git Bash to get the help, but I am getting an awful output.

Is there a way to fix that ?

[image: php artisan output]

Comment: those are terminal escape sequences for colors or something. e.g. you've got a bad terminal setting and the output doesn't conform to what your terminal window supports.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is due the Git Bash doesn't select anything when it's on "Default" Locale, and "Default" Character set.

**Changing to "en-US" and "UTF-8" solved the problem for me:**

[image]

**Steps in text:**

1. Open Git Bash
2. Right click top bar--> "Options"
3. on Left Side, Select "Text"
4. Change Locale to "en_US" and Chracter set to "UTF-8"
5. Apply/Save. Done.